# Nginx on front of node.js and apache

Tags: apache, node.js, nginx

I have nginx running on port 80 with a proxy pass for multiple node.js instances.

I'd like to also use nginx on the same port, to proxy for an apache instance running on another port, say 8888.

Here's the basics of my nginx.conf

```
   upstream localhost {
           server 127.0.0.1:8000;
           server 127.0.0.1:8001;
    }

    server {
            listen       80;
            server_name  localhost;

            location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost;
            }

            location /admin/ {
                proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:8888;
            }

    }
```

The two upstream's are node.js instances.  But the `/admin/` is for the site on apache, however it doens't work.

Is there another way to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
location /admin/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8888;
}
```

http://nginx.org/r/proxy_pass

Comment: Hm, doesn't seem to work.  Maybe a conflict with the upstream?

Comment: And what do you mean by "don't work"? Are you sure that your apache working and configured correctly?

Comment: It says: `Not Found The requested URL /admin/ was not found on this server.`, If I access the page directly though with port 8888 it works.  Apache is running.

Comment: What URL do you use to access it directly? There's a big difference between `http://127.0.0.1:8888/` and `http://127.0.0.1:8888/admin/`.

Comment: I use `http://127.0.0.1:8888/` to access it directly, then through Nginx, I was using `http://127.0.0.1:80/admin`

Comment: Ok.. Did you ever try to read the docs by the link in my answer? If you want to proxy to `http://127.0.0.1:8888/` (not `http://127.0.0.1:8888/admin/`) then you should use `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8888/;` (note the **trailing slash**).